# cant pass the parameter from one page to another page using navctrl and navparams

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem, i cant pass the value that initiate as 'any' to the page that i want using navctrl and navparams..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {RekomendasiPage} from '../rekomendasi/rekomendasi'

/**
 * Generated class for the LaporankesehatanPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-laporankesehatan',
  templateUrl: 'laporankesehatan.html',
})
export class LaporankesehatanPage {

  id: string;
  email : string;
  fullname : string;
  jeniskelamin : string;
  usia : number;
  berat : number;
  tinggi : number;
  bmi :number;
  hasil : string;
  category : number;
  kebutuhan : string;
  karbohidrat : number;
  protein_nabati : number;
  protein_hewani : number;
  lemak : number;
  gizi : any;
  test : string;


  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase,public fire :AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.id =this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.object('/user/'+this.id).subscribe(data => {              //ambil data user
      this.fullname = data.fullname;
      this.jeniskelamin = data.jeniskelamin;
      this.usia = data.usia;
      this.berat = data.berat;
      this.tinggi = data.tinggi;
      this.bmi = Number((this.berat/((this.tinggi/100)*(this.tinggi/100))));

// menghitung bmi
      if (this.bmi < 18.5 )
      {
        this.hasil="Berat badan kurang";
        this.category = 1;
      } 
      else if (this.bmi >= 18.5 && this.bmi <25)
      { 
        this.hasil = "Normal";
        this.category = 2;
      } 
      else if (this.bmi >= 25 && this.bmi <30 )
      {
        this.hasil = "Berat badan lebih";
        this.category = 3;
      }
      else
      {
        this.hasil = "obesitas";
        this.category =4;
      }
      console.log(this.hasil);
      console.log(this.bmi);    


    })
//mengecek kebutuhan porsi gizi
    if(this.category == 1)
    {
      this.kebutuhan = "3 Karbohidrat, 4 Protein hewani, 4 protein nabati, 2 lemak "
      this.gizi.karbohidrat=3;
      this.gizi.protein_hewani = 4;
      this.gizi.protein_nabati=4;
      this.gizi.lemak=2;
    }

    else if(this.category == 2)
    {
      this.kebutuhan = "3 Karbohidrat, 4 Protein hewani, 3 protein nabati,2 lemak "
      this.gizi.karbohidrat=3;
      this.gizi.protein_hewani = 4;
      this.gizi.protein_nabati=3
      this.gizi.lemak=2;
    }

    else if(this.category == 3)
    {
      this.kebutuhan = "3 Karbohidrat, 3 Protein hewani, 3 protein nabati, 2 lemak "
      this.gizi.karbohidrat=3;
      this.gizi.protein_hewani = 3;
      this.gizi.protein_nabati=3;
      this.gizi.lemak=2;
    }
    else
    {
      this.kebutuhan = "2 Karbohidrat, 3 Protein hewani, 3 protein nabati, 1 lemak "
      this.gizi.karbohidrat=2;
      this.gizi.protein_hewani = 3;
      this.gizi.protein_nabati=3;
      this.gizi.lemak=1;
    }
    console.log(this.gizi)

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LaporankesehatanPage');
  }

  cekMakanan(gizi)
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(RekomendasiPage,this.gizi);
  }

}
```

i want to fill the karbohidrat value,protein_hewani value, protein_nabati value and lemak value into one variable named gizi.
the error said : uncaught (in promise): cannot set property ' Karbohidrat' undefined

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through your code, I can see this assignment:

```
this.gizi.karbohidrat
```

Before `this.gizi` has been initialized. i.e.

```
this.gizi = {};
```

or

```
this.gizi = new Gizi();
```

etc.